# Reverse numeral input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get my code to print out the reverse of whatever integer is input. No errors, just not printing out correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int num, n;
int reverse(int);

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number less than 1000 to be reversed:" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    reverse(num);
    cout << "reversed number is:";
    getch();
    return 0;
}

int reverse(int num)
{
    long sum=0;int rem;

    while(n>0)
    {
        rem=n%10;
        sum=sum*10+rem;
        n=n/10;
        cout << sum << endl;
    }

    return sum;
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please show the input, output and the expected output.

Comment: input 234, output 234, expected output 432

Answer (score 2):

`n` is uninitialized in your program, yet you're using it in the `while` loop.

Try this:

```
int reverse(int num)
{
   int sum=0;
   while(num>0)
   {
     sum=sum*10+ num %10; 
     num=num/10;
   }
   return sum;
}
```

And since this function returns an integer which is reverse of the number which you passed to the function, you have to save the returned value, at the call-site as:

```
int revnum = reverse(num); //in your code, you're not doing this.
```

Now see the complete online demo : http://ideone.com/hLnS1

By the way, avoid global variables:

```
 int num, n; //avoid declaring these at global level.
```

Define them at local scope, as I did in the demo (see it).

Comment: What do I print in my main loop after I return? num??

Answer (score 0):

Reversing a number is easier if you treat it as a string.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 

int main()
{
    std::string sNum;

    std::cout << "Enter a number:" << std::flush;
    std::cin >> sNum;
    std::reverse(sNum.begin(), sNum.end());
    std::cout << "\nThe reverse is \"" << sNum << "\"";
    std::cout << "\n\nPress return to finish" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Produces

```
Enter a number:123456789

The reverse is "987654321"

Press return to finish
```

Comment: It is easier indeed. But slower.

Comment: @WPT - Why would it be slower?  cin/cout operate on character data, so we have conversion to and from an int and then at least as many operations as the string reverse.